# Request entity was not found

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to send message to android device by token using python and firebase but when I run the code I get error on line `response = messaging.send(message)`

```py
THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
my_file = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, 'wp-crawler-6265d-firebase-adminsdk-kyj8v-d7ccfaa311.json')

cred = credentials.Certificate(my_file)

 firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
'databaseURL': 'https://wp-crawler-6265d.firebaseio.com/'
})

for i in range(10):
    registration_token = "my key"

    message = messaging.Message(
        android=messaging.AndroidConfig(
            ttl=datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600),
            priority='normal',
            notification=messaging.AndroidNotification(
            title='$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
            body='$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
        ),
    ),
    token=registration_token,
)
response = messaging.send(message)
print('Successfully sent message:', response)
end = time. time()
print("TIME: ", end-start)
```

Comment: Error says Requested entity not found

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct: you define `message` inside the `for` loop, but then try to use it outside of the loop.

If you want to send 10 messages, move the `send` call *into* the loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    registration_token = "my key"

    message = messaging.Message(
        android=messaging.AndroidConfig(
            ttl=datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600),
            priority='normal',
            notification=messaging.AndroidNotification(
                title='$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
                body='$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
            ),
        ),
        token=registration_token,
    )
    print('Successfully sent message:', response)
    end = time. time()
    print("TIME: ", end-start)
```